# Entering the Schengen area for marriage purposes without meeting tourist visa requirements

Tags: visa, marriage

We are an international couple (I am from Italy, my partner is from Iran). Until now we always overcame Schengen visa requirements by meeting in Turkey, where we can both enter with just an ID card.

The Italian embassy in Teheran is plagued with corruption, it's basically impossible to even get an appointment for applying and this situation has not changed in 3 years.

I have a salary that could sustain both of us, a place to stay and we would like to be together for finally getting married here. Since Italy does not provide a marriage visa, the official guideline is to apply for a tourist visa. A proof of employment, property and an appropriate bank account budget are required in order to process and pass the visa request.

My partner is currently unemployed, and has no properties. Given the fact that these fair requests are made to avoid illegal immigration and overstaying under a tourist visa, but our purpose is to create a family and live together, is there a way to bypass these requirements that make no sense for us and also prevent us to accomplish one of the basic human rights like having a family?

I want to make clear that the Italian consulate in Teheran does not provide civil office services, so getting married in Iran is not possible, and the Iranian marriage has no value in Italy. Turkey provides a civil marriage under the Monaco Treaty but only for residents and Iranian authorities in Turkey do not allow a foreigner to marry outside the country, stating that they are not authorized to release the appropriate documentation.

What is going to happen if we just show up at the border without a visa but with the intention of marriage that will be confirmed by the marriage itself afterwards?

This is my only idea left.

Thanks for your replies. This is not meant to be a desperate or sentimental appeal, I just hope this community can help me like it always happened before.

Comment: If your partner shows up without a visa, it's more likely that he/she will be denied entry. Why don't you go to a country where your partner isn't required to get a visa (Armenia for example) and get married there? Certificates released by the Armenian officials have a value in Italy. Once you get that marriage certificate he/she will have the same right of freedom of movement in Schengen countries as you and can't be denied entry.

Comment: Apparently [Serbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Iranian_citizens) is another possibility. There is quite a bit of info about this kind of thing on the web.

Comment: How long have you and your partner been together?  Have you ever lived together?  You may already qualify for EU freedom of movement as partners "in a durable relationship" if you can show evidence to that effect.  The criteria for "durable relationship" vary from country to country, however.  Easiest would be in Italy, which extends EU rights to the family of Italian citizens, but I do not know Italy's criteria for "durable relationship."

Comment: @TomasBy Unfortunately our time is limited and we don't want to add another language barrier or dealing with authorities of 3rd countries when i can have some support from my own country. Every nation asks authorization from Iranian authorities and whitout the guardian authorization we can't go far.
My idea was to make her ask at the border to be accepted as a refugee, after that she should be given a temporary access to the country, and we can get married in that timeframe and then drop the asylum request.

Comment: @phoog We lived togheter in Turkey for some months, but as far as i know Italy does not have this kind of concept, and even if i can show evidence of that the embassy in Teheran is completely out of reach for any service we can ask. They don't answer mails or phone calls either.

Comment: @Cicomameli you could try at the Greek land border with Turkey, then travel from Greece to Italy.